# Setting Content in a EditText

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am developing a android calculter and I want to add the number the user clicks when he clicks its button
i added the onclick like this

```
android:onClick="number(1)"
```

the number inside the brackets is the number that i want it to be appended inside the EditText
and the code of the main activity and the function is

```
public void number(int medo){
    EditText result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);
    result.setText(result.getText() + " " + medo);
}
```

but when i click any button while testing the app it crashes so may anybody tell me how to fix this but fast please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method needs to have a View parameter, which will contain the button you clicked.

So, your code could look like this:

```
public void number(View v) {
    EditText result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);
    // get the text from the button that was clicked and add it to the EditText
    result.setText(result.getText() + " " + ((Button)v).getText().toString());
}
```

You can't set the argument in XML. It should look like this:

```
android:onClick="number"
```

Comment: may u please add comments to explain this cause i am new to java programing

Answer (score 0):

Also i think you have to call toString.

```
result.getText().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

the onCLick should be a method that has a `view` parameter in it.
this `View` represents the View (in this case `Button`) was clicked.

you method should be like that:

```
public void number(View view)
```

to solve your problem i will suggest putting `android:tag` in the xml.
for the `Button` you showed you will do:

```
android:tag="1"
android:onClick="number"
```

and in the `number` function you will do something like that:

```
public void number(View view)
{
     result.setText(result.getText() + " " + view.getTag().toString);
}
```

in addition, i will highly suggest to make `result` to a global variable and initialize it in the `onCreate()` instead, it will make the code better and efficient